# How can i downsample a 16khz wav file after doing FFT on the wav file

Tags: python, fft, downsampling

I extracted a wav file then applied the FFT
the sampling frequency is 16khz how can i downsample it and plot it to see the difference
also if you check fft_spectrum_abs.size it should return 8001 can i instead just take 265 points and just plot them ?

```
from numpy.fft  import fft
from numpy.fft import ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
%matplotlib inline
fft_spectrum = np.fft.rfft(amplitude)
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(signal.size, d=1./fs)
fft_spectrum_abs = np.abs(fft_spectrum)

plt.plot(freq, fft_spectrum_abs)
plt.xlabel("frequency, Hz")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude, units")
plt.show()
```